# prepend() item once per div

Tags: jquery, prepend

I have a dynamic select function and when a click is performed I want to prepend only once per div within.

So far my code just prepends every time. I just can't figure it out. Any advice is appreciated, thank you.

```
var selGroup = $(".selected-results > .results-group");

if (!$('.selected-results > .results-group > .results-category').length) {
  selGroup.prepend('<li class="results-category" data-class="'
    + category +'">'+ category +'</li>');
  return true;
} else {
}
```

Comment: Your `if` statement should prevent multiple appends, so logic would dictate that the condition is flawed. We cannot debug this without seeing a more representative example, though.

Comment: I'll try and get a better example up, sorry

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I figured out my resolution.

```
$(".selected-results > .results-group").each(function() {

        if ($(this).children('.results-category').length){
          return false;
        } 
        else {
          $(this).prepend('<li class="results-category" data-class="'+ category +'">'+ category +'<span class="show-more"></span></li>');
        }

      });
```